# How to do conditional bean creation using SPEL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-el

I have two beans in my application context and a property ${applicationType}

```
BeanTypeA
<bean id="beanTypeA" class="com.ext.library.A">
    <constructor-arg><value>boot</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

BeanTypeB
<bean id="beanTypeB" class="com.ext.library.B">
    <constructor-arg><value>boot</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

How do I control which beans to be created based on the SPEL in xml configurations using the property ${applicationType}

I am already using spring profiles for a different purpose in the application. So in this case, I won't be able to overload multiple spring profiles. Trying to achieve the conditional creation of bean using SPEL.

Thanks for the inputs.